# How to consolidate results from multiple IEnumerable<T> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I could have multiple (upto 5) `IEnumerable<ResortSupplier>` and would like to consolidate them into single `IEnumerable<ResortSupplier>` grouping by SupplierCode. My objects looks like this:

Here are my objects:

```
[Serializable]
public class ResortSupplier
{
    public string SupplierCode { get; set; }
    public IList<Product> ResortProducts { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Product
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    //Other fields... 
    public IList<PerPricing> PricingDetail { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class PerPricing
{
    //Other fields..
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public Error PricingError { get; set; }
}
```

Data in multiple IEnumerable could look like this:

```
----------------------------------------
IEnumerable<ResortSupplier> - 1

Hyatt Resort
  Standard Room
    PricingDetail-1
  Superior Room         
    PricingDetail-1

Sandals Resort
  Standard Room
    PricingDetail-1
  Delux Room            
    PricingDetail-1

----------------------------------------
IEnumerable<ResortSupplier> - 2

Hyatt Resort
  Standard Room
    PricingDetail-2
  Superior Room         
    PricingDetail-2
  One Bed Room Suit
    PricingDetail-2

Sandals Resort
  Standard Room
    PricingDetail-2
  Honeymoon Suit            
    PricingDetail-2
----------------------------------------
IEnumerable<ResortSupplier> - 3
.....
----------------------------------------
IEnumerable<ResortSupplier> - 4
.....
----------------------------------------
IEnumerable<ResortSupplier> - 5
.....
----------------------------------------
```

My consolidated result should contain:

```
IEnumerable<ResortSupplier> - Consolidated

Hyatt Resort
  Standard Room
    PricingDetail-1
    PricingDetail-2
  Superior Room         
    PricingDetail-1
    PricingDetail-2
  Bed Room Suit
    PricingDetail-2

Sandals Resort
  Standard Room
    PricingDetail-1
    PricingDetail-2
  Delux Room            
    PricingDetail-1
  Honeymoon Suit            
    PricingDetail-2

----------------------------------------
```

What is the best way to handle this? I tried simple IEnumerable.Union and GroupBy clauses but doesn't get me the results I want.

Comment: FYI Union will remove duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
// You can construct this with an array if it isn't already in this form.
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<ResortSupplier>> supplierLists = ...

var query = from suppliers in supplierLists
            from supplier in suppliers
            group supplier by supplier.SupplierCode into g

            let products = g.SelectMany(s => s.ResortProducts)
                            .GroupBy(p => p.Code)
                            .Select(prodGroup => new Product
                                    {
                                       Code = prodGroup.Key,
                                       PricingDetail = prodGroup
                                                       .SelectMany(p => p.PricingDetail)
                                                       .ToList()
                                    })

            select new ResortSupplier
            {
                SupplierCode  = g.Key, 
                ResortProducts = products.ToList()                              
            };
```

That's a really horrible-looking query though. I strongly recommend factoring out the different components of the query into separate (well-named) methods.

Comment: Ani, I could have multiple `IEnumerable<ResortSupplier>` but not `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<ResortSupplier>>`. Do you want me to first build `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<ResortSupplier>>` from all `IEnumerable<ResortSupplier>`?

Comment: @Alex: Yes. For example: `var supplierLists = new[] { supplierList1, supplierList2, ... };`

Comment: Ani, That worked. Thanks. I also have a "LowestPrice" field in `ResortSupplier` which would contain the lowest price from all p.PricingDetail. How can I populate this field? I think I might have to use `.Min(p => p.Price)` function of LINQ but I am having hard time building a query.

Comment: I got the lowest price `SelectMany(p => p.PricingDetail).Min(p => p.Price)` BUT I want lowest non-zero price, if I use where clause such as `.Where(l => l.Price > 0).Min(p => p.Price)` it removes items with zero price, where clause acts as a filter and removes non-zero records. I want to keep all records intact and also get lowest non-zero price.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding you, you should use Concat to get them into one big collection, then you can group however you want

```
IEnumerable<ResortSupplier> master = 
    result1.Concat(result2).Concat(result3); //etc
```

Then group like you normally would:

```
var resultGrouped = master.GroupBy(rs => rs.SupplierCode);
```

Comment: Adam, Pls. see my comments for Martinho's post.

Comment: I think your question is worded incorrectly.  Calling concat on your 5 collections will pile them up into one.  Grouping this huge collection will...group it...by whatever you specify.  What exactly are you expecting and what is happening?

Comment: Adam, May be I didn't made it very clear while wording my question but my example shows what my expected results should be. I apologize for the confusion. Ani's solution worked for me. Thanks.